# Highcharts adding series for every selectbox selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts with MySQL and PHP... I have a Selectbox (Multiple Selections allowed) which contains company sections.
What I'm trying to do is create a new chart series for every selection the user chooses.

Example: If I choose from selectbox "option1,option2,option3" ... the chart will have 3 series for these 3 selected options. However, If I chose only option1, the chart will have only 1 series.

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Daily Volume of Calls',
        x: -20 //center
    },

    xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime'
    },
       plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(<?php echo $datefixed; ?>),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total Calls'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Calls'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: <?php echo $firstselection ?>,

        data: [<?php echo join($callsarray, ',') ?>]
    }, {
        name: <?php echo $secondselection ?>, //**<<< THE PROBLEM IS HERE**  
        showInLegend: true, 
        data: []
    }]
});
```

The problem on my code is if the variable `$secondselection` is empty or not set(meaning the user didn't chose more than 1 option), the chart will return a blank page even if `$firstselection` variable is set. But if the user chooses a second option, it will show fine.

Any help guys? :)

Comment: I am not sure why you have empty data array in the second series. You will always get data for one series. Why don't you load the data for all the series at the beggining and then just switch their visibility in js? http://jsfiddle.net/8mg1yhyt/

Comment: YES!! that's exactly what I needed, Thank you so much buddy :) .. Although this needs to change the select values to be numbers starting from 0, and I was using these values to determine which section the user chose to create the MySQL query.. but I can deal with that. :))